# Call application from another application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two deferent application, main application and small application. I want my small application to automatically run if my main application is running. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

use this intent for starting another app from your appliction:

```
Intent intent25 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("SMALL_APP_PACKAGE_NAME",
"SMALL_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.Testservice").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("SMALL_APP_PACKAGE_NAME",
"SMALL_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.Testservice"));
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent25);
```

Comment: i try with your suggest, but can't working..my small application is deferent project with my main application..thank you :)